# Mock a database to fetch resultset

Tags: junit, mocking, mockito

I need to mock with Mockito :

ResultSet rs = oracle.getConnection().getMetaData().getIndexInfo(null, null, table.getName(), true, true);

final ResultSetMetaData data = rs.getMetaData();

Comment: Please help me how to mock the above .thanks in anticipation

Comment: Which mocking framework do you use?

Comment: I need to mock : SettingsProvider.getSchema().getParent();after mocking it should return table name .

Comment: Hi Gerd, i use Mockito.

Comment: There is an insert method.it should construct insert query for a table.Based on the data type of the columns it constructs values. now i have mock metadata of the table to see if its constructing query for different datatypes.

Comment: Looking forward for your help . Thanks a lot  :)

Answer (score 0):

First, I've got an advice for you. Do not mock it. Really. There is a golden rule of mocks - mock what you own. So, no mocks for Connection, MetaData, ResultSet etc. You will get into troubles if you follow this path.

However, if you still want to do it, RETURNS_DEEP_STUB is what you are looking for:
http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS